# Creat a list of variables with a specific prefix

Tags: python, list

I have a series of variables called pic1, pic2, pic3 etc.
I want to create a list of all the variables that begin with "pic"

the long way would be as follows

```
piclist = [pic1,pic2,pic3,...]
```

there must be a shorter way?

thanks in advance

Comment: The KEY is not to create them as `pic1`, `pic2` etc in the first place.  Store them in a list (or dictionary) to begin with.  Solutions involving `globals` are just a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the variables are defined in module level. If yes you can use `globals()` which returns *a dictionary containing the current scope's global variables*

```
>>> pic1 = 1
>>> pic2 = 2
>>>
>>> [globals()[key] for key in globals() if key.startswith("pic")]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Although this technically answers the question, this is a Bad Idea.  The right answer is to create the list to begin with.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have made use of many lists and dictionaries in other parts of my script., however, these variables didn't end up being coded into a list.  I am constantly reviewing and trying to improve, however, this time round I need a solution to work quickly.  I am sure you appreciated that there are always times we don't write things perfectly the first time round.